# Mongodb use $elemMatch sub document other fields in group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to count number of subscribe actions per day.
and here is my user_events collection :

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 5,
        "events": [
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-17T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "subscribe" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-18T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "unsubscribe" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-16T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "charge" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-19T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "subscribe" 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_id": 6,
        "events": [
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-6T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "subscribe" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-17T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "unsubscribe" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-10T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "charge" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-26T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "send-code" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-11T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "charge" 
            },
            {
                "date": ISODate("2018-10-18T15:51:06.000Z"),
                "action": "subscribe" 
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I need to aggregate data based on subscribe date.
so just sub documents with action : subscribe should be counted in query result.

so my result should be :

```
{"2018-10-18": 2, "2018-10-06": 1, "2018-10-17":2, "2018-10-19":1}
```

please consider that I only want sub documents with subscribe action to be counted in my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this via something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      events: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$events",
          as: "event",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$event.action",
              "subscribe"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$events"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      day: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$events.date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$day",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The idea is first to [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the `subscribe` events after which we [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html).

Then add the day field (via [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html)) on which we would be [grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) in the last phase.

You can see this [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4RtLwUwAPVM)

You can also append:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "day": "$_id",
      "count": "$count"
    }
  }
```

If you would like to get `day` instead of the `_id`